# como imprimir los datos de un input en un <h1> en javascript y html

Tags: javascript, html5, array

Mi problema consta en que al introducir los datos a un input, solamente los imprima luego de hacer click en el botón enviar. 
Pero no se la razón por la cual es que mi código no los imprime en el `<H1>`. 
Ademas me gustaría saber como poder comprobar si el usuario a llenado todos los inputs de texto y si no mostrarle un mensaje para que los llene.

mi html es.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="work js/form.js"></script>
    <title>formulario</title>
    <link href="rcss/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="cabeza">
        <form action="" id="formulario">

        <label id="engreso"for="">ingrese sus datos</label>

        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"  >

            <input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" >

            <input type="date" name="fecha" class="sendit" onchange="edad(event);">

            <input type="email" id="emai" placeholder="Example@mailserv.com">

        <input type="button" value="enviar" name="boton" onclick="sub()" >

    </form>
    </div>    

   <div id="cuerpo">

    <h1 id="yax">Cuales son sus datos</h1>

    <h1 id="nom">Su nombre</h1>

    <h1 id="yax">Cual es su apellido</h1>

    <h1 id="ape">su apellido</h1>

    <h1 id="yax">Cual es su edad</h1>

    <h1 id="eda">su edad</h1>

    <h1 id="yax">Cual es su correo</h1>

    <h1 id="mai">su email</h1>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi Javascript es

```
function sub(){
    var nombre = null;
    var correo = null;
    var apellido = null;

    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
    correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;

    document.getElementById('nom').innerHTML = nombre;
    document.getElementById('ape').innerHTML = apellido;
    document.getElementById('mai').innerHTML = correo;

}
    function edad(e) {
    edadM = Date.parse(Date()) - Date.parse(e.target.value);
    edads = new Date();
    edads.setTime(edadM);
    resultado = edads.getFullYear() - 1970;
    res = (resultado <= 0) ? 0 : resultado; // Para evitar que sea negativo
    document.getElementById('eda').innerHTML = res;}
```

me gustaría saber como imprimir los inputs de nombre, apellido, y correo en un `<h1>` gracias por su timepo.

Answer (score 1):

para validar que los datos no esten vacios en tu funcion java script debes validarlos con un if por ejemplo

```
    function sub(){
        var nombre = null;
        var correo = null;
        var apellido = null;

        nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
        correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
      /// validacion de nombres
       if (nombre === '' || apellido === '' || correo === ''){
       alert("favor de llenar todos los campos")
       }

    para imprimir correctamente los nombres debes referenciar el valor del input en donde los quieres imprimir por ejemplo:

<span id="userInfo"></span><br />

 y dentro de una funcion :

        nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
        correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
  document.getElementById('userInfo').innerHTML = nombre + ' ' + apellido + ' ' + correo;
```

Comment: pero para imprimir eso datos en un `<h1>` como seria?

Answer (score 1):

lo que esta haciendo que se caiga es esto:

```
correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
```

Ya que no existe un input con ese id, deberas cambiarlo a `emai` que es como lo tienes en el HTML.

Para validar si los campos van vacíos puedes utilizar un `if` y comparar los valores obtenidos para que no sean vacíos. En caso de ser vació mostrar algún mensaje.

```js
function sub() {
  var nombre = null;
  var correo = null;
  var apellido = null;


  nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
  correo = document.getElementById("emai").value;

  if ("" != nombre && "" != apellido && "" != correo) {
    document.getElementById('nom').innerHTML = nombre;
    document.getElementById('ape').innerHTML = apellido;
    document.getElementById('mai').innerHTML = correo;
  } else {
    alert('Ingrese todos los datos');
    return false;
  }
}

function edad(e) {
  edadM = Date.parse(Date()) - Date.parse(e.target.value);
  edads = new Date();
  edads.setTime(edadM);
  resultado = edads.getFullYear() - 1970;
  res = (resultado <= 0) ? 0 : resultado; // Para evitar que sea negativo
  document.getElementById('eda').innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="work js/form.js"></script>
  <title>formulario</title>
  <link href="rcss/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <div id="cabeza">
      <form action="" id="formulario">

        <label id="engreso" for="">ingrese sus datos</label>

        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" >

        <input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">

        <input type="date" name="fecha" class="sendit" onchange="edad(event);">

        <input type="email" id="emai" placeholder="Example@mailserv.com">

        <input type="button" value="enviar" name="boton" onclick="sub()">

      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="cuerpo">

      <h1 id="yax">Cuales son sus datos</h1>

      <h1 id="nom">Su nombre</h1>

      <h1 id="yax">Cual es su apellido</h1>

      <h1 id="ape">su apellido</h1>

      <h1 id="yax">Cual es su edad</h1>

      <h1 id="eda">su edad</h1>

      <h1 id="yax">Cual es su correo</h1>

      <h1 id="mai">su email</h1>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```